# Can't get handlebars partials to work with Express

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm new to express and handlebars and I'm trying to make some basic templating using partials...

I'm getting a "partial could not be found" error.

*dependencies in package.json file*

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.15.5",
    "hbs": "~4.0.1",
    "mongodb": "^3.0.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.0.0-rc0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.4.5"
  }
```

*app.js file snippet*

```
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// register path to partials
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/partials');
```

*index.hbs view file*

```
{{> header }}

{{> left-sidebar }}

{{> right-sidebar }}
```

I put these partials in a subfolder of the "views" folder in my project.

Any help on what I'm missing?

Comment: For anyone with a similar problem in the future...

I fixed this by changing my partial includes to use underscores like so: {{> left_sidebar }} and {{> right_sidebar}}. The actual include files are named with hyphens, but hyphens did not work in my partials calls in index.hbs file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The missing piece is there is no support for **Kebab Case** (*Hypen-separated*) in Javascript for a variable. Since partials in handlebars are variables `{{> left-sidebar }}` wont work.

Cheers.